# Thin processes die without message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thin

I have two Thin servers running for a Rails app. I start them up with `bundle exec thin start`.

```
chdir: /[root]/current
environment: production
address: 0.0.0.0
port: 3001
timeout: 30
log: /[root]/log/thin.log
pid: tmp/pids/thin.pid
max_conns: 1024
max_persistent_conns: 100
require: []
wait: 30
threadpool_size: 20
servers: 2
daemonize: true
```

When I wait a few hours usually one of the two servers is gone (e.g., only see one with `htop` or with `pgrep -lf thin`). And even worse, sometimes *both* of them are gone after 10 hours or so which results in a 500 error via the browser. Furthermore, when I start 3 or 4 servers 2 of the 4 processes die within 1 minute on average.

I don't see error messages in my Rails `production.log` nor in the `thin.[port]` log files specified in the `app.yml` file.

Is there a way to keep the Thin servers running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you can run your server with `bundle exec -C app.yml start`?
Try `bundle exec thin -C app.yml start`

Comment: Can server visit well when thin start? I have used thin for at least four of my web application and run almost month without problem. Check if memory is enough or another service inpact it?

Comment: Ah how much memory does it need. I have only about 100 MB ram with 96 used.

Comment: 100MB ran can run server but soon after the memory may not enough, if you want to run server with two processes, I think 512MB ram may enough. Its also depend on your application scale.

Comment: I run one Ruby application and one WordPress one on the server. This might be the reason the Thin processes (and also the Wordpress one sometimes) are killed?

Comment: The answer is in your comment. I requested more memory (128MB RAM instead of 64M, and now the servers run fine! Thanks!